# AlphaToCoverage + Alpha Blending = Artifacts

Tags: opengl, rendering, blending

I'm experiencing a strange problem using OpenGL SampleAlphaToCoverage mode. There are rendering artifacts when using alpha-blending on pixels that have been rendered using alpha-to-coverage - and I can't explain why.

Here's the basic setup:

1. Render the world. Some batches of vertices are rendered using alpha-to-coverage. Blending is **never** enabled at this stage.
2. Disable depth testing an render a **screen overlay**. At this point I'm using alpha blending. Alpha-to-coverage is **never** enabled at this stage.

I'm using alpha-to-coverage on the airplanes glass window. This is what the scene looks like:
[image: Works as expected]

Everything works as expected so far. However, as soon the screen overlays alpha blending is drawn at a screen location where alpha-to-coverage has been previously active, I'm getting this:
[image: Blending artifacts]

Note that there is **no error** as long as blending affects different pixels than alpha-to-coverage!
[image]

I also tested the following cases:

- Use alpha-to-coverage for the overlay instead of alpha blending: No artifacts.
- Clear the entire screen before rendering the screen overlay: No artifacts.
- Clear all buffers except the color buffer: Artifacts
- Clear only the color buffer: No artifacts

The screen overlay item in question consists of a single textured Quad. The texture is 256x256.

You can download the test application at http://www.fetzenet.de/atc_error.zip
Camera controls are WASD + Mouse (Hold left or right button)

Does anyone have a clue whats going on here? Also, can anyone reproduce this behavior?

Comment: Tried playing with glSampleCoverage()?

Comment: Is the MSAA resolve occurring before or after the screen overlay pass?

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek Can you tell me how to find out? I'm rendering both in a single frame and do nothing special.. Is there a way to trigger an MSAA resolve explicitly?

Comment: @MichaelSlade Yes, I set it to 1.0f when rendering the overlay, but that didn't change anything.